# Cannot get / with encore dev-server in Symfony

Tags: symfony, webpack-dev-server, webpack-encore

*I would like to point out that I am on a classic Symfony application with the default configuration for Webpack. And that the watch command works very well.*

Hello,
When I try to start the Webpack Encore development server, the compilation is done without any problem but when I access the page, I get the error "Cannot GET /". I have no errors in the console

[image: Error]
<sub>(source: [casimages.com](https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/08/18/190818104256873510.png))</sub>

But interestingly, `http://localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server` seems to work.
[image: Load]
<sub>(source: [casimages.com](https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/08/18/190818104442154533.png))</sub>

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')ne CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    .splitEntryChunks()

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    //.enableSassLoader()
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
    .enableReactPreset()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

I got "Cannot GET /" when trying to reach the server through localhost. Finally Iil I let Symfony open the webpage with the command:

**symfony open:local**

It opened on https://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score -2):

You can check if your files are created in `public/build` folder. If your files are created completely check if they have appropriate access to read.

Comment: I'm on Windows. And yes, because the watcher works. Only web-server doesn't work